# How to perform NMF (Negative Matrix Factorisation) on the particular small matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, machine-learning, svd, nonnegative-matrices

I read in the literature that SVD and NMF are somehow similar. Withou the probelm I am able to manually perform SVD on the matrix
$$Z= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}.$$
But cannot find the way to make the decomposition for NMF, i.e. $Z = WH$. (**NOT USING PROGRAMMING**). Can you help please?

A small description of NMF:
[image]

Comment: Do you have a reference for Negative Matrix Factorization ? Indeed, it's not common...

Comment: @JeanMarie  I added the refference to NMF in the question (screenshot)

Comment: Thank you very much...